cant use get static props with server side props , is there any other way to get referer url dynamically?
So in my use case I want to use both server side rendering and static generation . Here is my use case
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
    const store = initializeStore({ ssr: true });
    // fetch filters and all static data for the page 
    return {
        props: {
            menuHierarchyCms,
            filterCmsData: shownFilters,
            sortCmsData: sortMenuCms,
        },
    };
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    console.log(context.req.headers.referer);
    return {
        props: {
            refer: context.req.headers.referer,
        },
    };
}

is there any way I can use both ? as I need server side to render search results when the user first visits the page using query params and all subsequent requests are client side rendered as user will type search in input box
I tried using both ssr and static generation but it failed as nextjs doesnt suppport it . ISR does not support context referrer and server side rendering on each request
